# I can choose the Image only after restarting the Program (JAVA/FX)

Tags: java, javafx

My Program got an ChoiceBox where i choose Images and after i choose one it automaticly updates the ImageView perfectly but if i upload a new Image in the Choicebox and i want to change the Image to the new one it thows an Exeception.
But when i restart the Program i can select the new Image without any problems.

```
    mCb_img.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(o -> {

        mIv_img.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResource("/img/" + mCb_img.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()).toExternalForm()));
    });
```

---

```
@FXML
private void changeOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
    File img = null;
    Path source = null;
    Path target = null;

    imgfileChooser.setTitle("Open Image File");
    imgfileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG", "*.jpg"));
    img = imgfileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
    source = img.toPath();
    if (img != null) {
        try {
            File saved = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/im"
                    + "g/" + source.getFileName());
            target = saved.toPath();
            Files.move(source, target);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    mCb_img.getItems().add(source.getFileName().toString());
   // fillChoiceBox();

}
```

---

```
private void fillChoiceBox() {
    mCb_img.getItems().clear();
    try {

        Files.walk(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/img/"))
                .forEach(filePath -> {
                    if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                        mCb_img.getItems().add(filePath.getFileName()
                                .toString());
                    }
                });
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("No files in IMG!");
    }
    mCb_img.getSelectionModel().select(0);
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at zweitehu.FXMLDocumentController.lambda$setListeners$1(FXMLDocumentController.java:248)
at zweitehu.FXMLDocumentController$$Lambda$219/404494396.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(SingleSelectionModel.java:223)
at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.select(SingleSelectionModel.java:149)
at javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox$ChoiceBoxSelectionModel.select(ChoiceBox.java:402)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ChoiceBoxSkin.lambda$addPopupItem$266(ChoiceBoxSkin.java:259)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ChoiceBoxSkin$$Lambda$227/143169386.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1364)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$324(ContextMenuContent.java:1317)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$$Lambda$231/1415399751.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: please add source code to your question, otherwise it is just guesswork

Comment: The zweitehu.FXMLDocumentController.lambda$setListeners$1(FXMLDocumentController.java, line 248 seems to have interesting content.

Comment: @BjörnKautler Added code

Comment: Which of the code snippets is what? Where is FXMLDocumentController.java:248?

Comment: @BjörnKautler Sorry i am new the mIv_img.setImage in the Listner is FXMLDocumentController.java:248

Comment: @JoopEggen Its the mIv_img.setImage in the Listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You copy the file to the source directory, which means the file will only be available using `Class.getResource` after you package the application again (or let your ide copy it to the classpath or appropriate equivalent for your setup).

If you want to access the new images at runtime, use the `URL` to the files instead of the `URL` you get using `Class.getResource`:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView();

ComboBox<Path> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Path>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(Path object) {
        return object.getFileName().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Path fromString(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

});

iv.imageProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    Path path = comboBox.getValue();

    // use url for the given path
    return path == null ? null : new Image(path.toUri().toURL().toExternalForm());
}, comboBox.valueProperty()));
```

And use paths as item type in the `ComboBox`:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/img/"))
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .forEach(comboBox.getItems()::add);
```

Also add the target path to the `ComboBox`, not the source path(`changeOnAction`):

```
Files.move(source, target);
comboBox.getItems().add(target);
```